# VSCode: Auto import/import suggestions for Python dependencies from external libraries

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, autocomplete, dependencies

I'm using VSCode for Python programming. One project heavily relies on an external library and often needs to load modules/classes/etc from that library.

When I type a class that is not yet imported and click on "quick fix" (cmd + . on Mac), VSCode automatically suggests what to import.
Unfortunately, these suggestions only involve modules from the currently open project - not from any external dependency.

This means, I always have to figure out how to import the missing class from the external library (which package) and manually add the import myself. This is quite tedious when required frequently.

Is there any way to have VSCode auto suggest and import missing debendencies/classes/etc from external libraries similar to what it does with imports from the open project?

I found the setting `python.autoComplete.extraPaths` and set it to

```json
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [  
   "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mylib"
]
```

but I couldn't notice any change and the auto import still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What finally worked for me is this setting:

```json
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "~/Projects/mylib"
    ],
    "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": false,
    "python.analysis.packageIndexDepths": [
        {
            "name": "mylib",
            "depth": 5,
            "includeAllSymbols": false
        }
    ],
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "~/Projects/mylib"
    ],
```

With this, I can add missing imports simply with Cmd + . (on MacOS).
If setting `autoImportCompletions` to true, it would even add the imports automatically.

Thanks MingJie for the hint regarding the index depth. This was certainly a key issue.
Not sure if the relative paths and the `analysis.extraPaths` was really needed, but now everything works.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, vscode only performs first-class retrieval. We can add the following content to make vscode perform deep retrieval:

```
"python.analysis.packageIndexDepths":[["sqlalchemy",2]],
```

In this example, sqlalchemy.orm is 2 level deep.

Of course, the load on hardware will also be greater.

You can also use [["",2]], it will change default depth.

You can refer to this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2533#issuecomment-1089268739) in github for more information.

Comment: Setting the packageIndexDepths to a proper value does help with autocompletion when writing an import statement.
What still does not work are [Quick Fixes](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_quick-fixes), which are supposed to suggest a missing import. I thought this would work with my packageIndexDepth set correctly, but it still doesn't. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: @CGFoX Can [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3648) in github help?

Answer (score 0):

How something so basic on Eclipse IDE just use "Control + Shift + O" and it will add all the missing imports. If there are two classes with the same name it will ask you which to use.
Not having this on Python is terrible.

Comment: I eventually found a setting that works for me. See my newly added answer.